# Loop Label names in userform picking text from worksheet range

Tags: vba, for-loop, label, userform, caption

I have 27 labels (ex - label 500 to 526) in userform and each label has to pick the name from a range (sheet1- range b4 to b30). If the label name is empty respective text box (textbox 500 to 526) should hide. Need help in looping this code.

```
proviate sub teamlistchange()

    Label500.Caption = Worksheets("SME - Data classification").Range("b4").Value
Label501.Caption = Worksheets("SME - Data classification").Range("b5").Value
Label502.Caption = Worksheets("SME - Data classification").Range("b6").Value
Label503.Caption = Worksheets("SME - Data classification").Range("b7").Value
Label504.Caption = Worksheets("SME - Data classification").Range("b8").Value
Label505.Caption = Worksheets("SME - Data classification").Range("b9").Value
Label506.Caption = Worksheets("SME - Data classification").Range("b10").Value
Label507.Caption = Worksheets("SME - Data classification").Range("b11").Value
Label508.Caption = Worksheets("SME - Data classification").Range("b12").Value
Label509.Caption = Worksheets("SME - Data classification").Range("b13").Value
Label510.Caption = Worksheets("SME - Data classification").Range("b14").Value
Label511.Caption = Worksheets("SME - Data classification").Range("b15").Value
Label512.Caption = Worksheets("SME - Data classification").Range("b16").Value
Label513.Caption = Worksheets("SME - Data classification").Range("b17").Value
Label514.Caption = Worksheets("SME - Data classification").Range("b18").Value
Label515.Caption = Worksheets("SME - Data classification").Range("b19").Value
Label516.Caption = Worksheets("SME - Data classification").Range("b20").Value
Label517.Caption = Worksheets("SME - Data classification").Range("b21").Value
Label518.Caption = Worksheets("SME - Data classification").Range("b22").Value
Label519.Caption = Worksheets("SME - Data classification").Range("b23").Value
Label520.Caption = Worksheets("SME - Data classification").Range("b24").Value
Label521.Caption = Worksheets("SME - Data classification").Range("b25").Value
Label522.Caption = Worksheets("SME - Data classification").Range("b26").Value
Label523.Caption = Worksheets("SME - Data classification").Range("b27").Value
Label524.Caption = Worksheets("SME - Data classification").Range("b28").Value
Label525.Caption = Worksheets("SME - Data classification").Range("b29").Value
Label526.Caption = Worksheets("SME - Data classification").Range("b30").Value

'SDM activities hide empty cells
If Label500.Caption = "" Then TextBox500.Visible = False
If Label501.Caption = "" Then TextBox501.Visible = False
If Label502.Caption = "" Then TextBox502.Visible = False
If Label503.Caption = "" Then TextBox503.Visible = False
If Label504.Caption = "" Then TextBox504.Visible = False
If Label505.Caption = "" Then TextBox505.Visible = False
If Label506.Caption = "" Then TextBox506.Visible = False
If Label507.Caption = "" Then TextBox507.Visible = False
If Label508.Caption = "" Then TextBox508.Visible = False
If Label509.Caption = "" Then TextBox509.Visible = False
If Label510.Caption = "" Then TextBox510.Visible = False
If Label511.Caption = "" Then TextBox511.Visible = False
If Label512.Caption = "" Then TextBox512.Visible = False
If Label513.Caption = "" Then TextBox513.Visible = False
If Label514.Caption = "" Then TextBox514.Visible = False
If Label515.Caption = "" Then TextBox515.Visible = False
If Label516.Caption = "" Then TextBox516.Visible = False
If Label517.Caption = "" Then TextBox517.Visible = False
If Label518.Caption = "" Then TextBox518.Visible = False
If Label519.Caption = "" Then TextBox519.Visible = False
If Label520.Caption = "" Then TextBox520.Visible = False
If Label521.Caption = "" Then TextBox521.Visible = False
If Label522.Caption = "" Then TextBox522.Visible = False
If Label523.Caption = "" Then TextBox523.Visible = False
If Label524.Caption = "" Then TextBox524.Visible = False
If Label525.Caption = "" Then TextBox525.Visible = False
If Label526.Caption = "" Then TextBox526.Visible = False

end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
proviate Sub teamlistchange()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 500 To 526

Controls("Label" & i).Caption = Worksheets("SME - Data classification").Range(Cells(i,2)).Value
If Controls("Label" & i).Caption = "" Then Controls("TextBox" & i).Visible = False

Next i
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, however, i am receiving an error for "Controls("Label" & i).Caption = Worksheets("SME - Data classification").Range(Cells(i,2)).Value"

Comment: "Worksheets("SME - Data classification").Range(Cells(i,2)).Value" here the range is b4 to b30.

Comment: any luck on finding a solution for this??

Comment: What kind of Error do you get?

Comment: it says application defined or object defined error. I think while defining range we gave worksheets("SME - Data classification").range(celld(i,2)).value. Here i starts with 500. however, my rage is "b4:b30". Do you think this is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Its resolved!!

```
Private Sub TeamListChange()

Const iCONTROL_NO_FIRST As Integer = 500
Const iCONTROL_NO_LAST  As Integer = 526
Const sPREFIX_TEXTBOX   As String = "TextBox"
Const sPREFIX_LABEL     As String = "Label"
Const sLABEL_COLUMN     As String = "B"
Const sSHEET_NAME       As String = "SME - Data classification"
Const iOFFSET           As Integer = 496

Dim iLabelRowNo         As Integer
Dim sLabelText          As String
Dim rLabelCell          As Range
Dim iControlNo          As Integer
Dim wks                 As Worksheet

Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sSHEET_NAME)

With Me

    For iControlNo = iCONTROL_NO_FIRST To iCONTROL_NO_LAST

        iLabelRowNo = iControlNo - iOFFSET

        Set rLabelCell = wks.Range(sLABEL_COLUMN & CStr(iLabelRowNo))

        sLabelText = rLabelCell.Value

        .Controls(sPREFIX_LABEL & CStr(iControlNo)).Caption = sLabelText

        If sLabelText = vbNullString Then
            .Controls(sPREFIX_TEXTBOX & CStr(iControlNo)).Visible = False
        End If

    Next iControlNo

End With
```

End Sub